# Convert a string into a number in Pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am having trouble solving one assignment. Well, in a dataframe in one column I have values as text strings (objects). I want to convert this to a numeric value but every time I get an error that I cannot convert the string to a float.
I want to try using regex to convert the string '-1 203.45' into the value '1203.45'. Please help me how the code should be written in Pandas.

I've tested virtually all of the forum hints and none of them work. Please give me a hint.

Comment: Can you show us what work you have done so far?

Comment: Why are you turning a negative number into a positive one?

Comment: Are there always spaces in these numbers? Or was this a mistake in the question?

Comment: If you just want to remove the space, you can use ``thousands=" "``  when loading the dataframe to convert it to float.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First what I did:

1. Read the file csv in different way:

   df = pd.read_csv('dane_navision.csv', delimiter=";", decimal= ",",
   thousands=" " )

and

```
df = pd.read_table('dane_navision.csv', delimiter=";", thousands=" ", decimal=',')
```

I receive such table:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1905 entries, 0 to 1904
Data columns (total 14 columns):
 #   Column                      Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------                      --------------  -----  
 0   Data księgowania            1905 non-null   object 
 1   Typ zapisu                  1905 non-null   object 
 2   Nr zapisu                   1905 non-null   int64  
 3   Nr dokumentu                1905 non-null   object 
 4   Nr zapasu                   1905 non-null   object 
 5   Opis                        1905 non-null   object 
 6   Kod lokalizacji             1905 non-null   object 
 7   Ilość                       1905 non-null   object 
 8   Ilość zafakturowana         1905 non-null   object 
 9   MPK - kod                   1905 non-null   object 
 10  Nr dok.zewn.                0 non-null      float64
 11  Kod kategorii zapasu        1826 non-null   object 
 12  Ilość na jednostkę miary    1905 non-null   int64  
 13  Kwota kosztu (rzeczywista)  1905 non-null   object 
dtypes: float64(1), int64(2), object(11)
memory usage: 208.5+ KB
```

For me is important 13 column. I wanted to change them from object to float and I can't do it.

I get the following error every time:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '-1xa0032.02'

I tried many ways with the method:
`df['colum_name'].astype(float)` - does not work.
`df['column_name'].str.replace[" ", "" ]` - does not work.
Maybe someone has some idea how to cut space from string and then it will be easier to convert it to number.

Comment: I found the reason why standard operations don't work. 
The csv file was exported from the accounting system. Unfortunately in this system the spearator of thousands is a "space" - however, it is not a space but some special system character pretending to be a "white sign". 
Now the question is how to remove such a sign from the text string?